# Cant install HAXM (Android Studio, AMD Processor)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, amd-processor

I am trying to install HAXM to emulate an android app but I keep getting this error

```
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information."
```

I have enabled/disabled Hyper-V and enabled Windows Hypervisor Platform.
I cant even install the Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD. I get this error:

```
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1062:

The service has not been started.

[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS
[SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201.
HAXM documentation for more information."
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out I dont even need to install HAXM, you can just create a virtual device with a x86 os (not x86_64 so that your not prompted to install HAXM).

Comment: Nope... I tried it and I still get `Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
HAXM is not installed.`